# Table design for payments

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a table that holds data for a person who is on a project. The table has a `Start` date field a nullable `End` date field. So, a person is on a project from `Start` to `End`.

At the moment, they are always billable to the project. But I now have a new requirement that, for a period, they can be non-billable, yet, still working on the project. So, they have been assigned to the project, and are working, but for some reason, the client isn't billed for part of the period they are assigned, or maybe billed at a lower rate.

My idea is to have an exclusion type table, linked to the person assignment table which would have a start date, and end date, and a `Rate` column, which could be set to zero for no-charge, or else, works as an override value for a period.

Does this seem like valid design? As the person is billed 95% of the time, and probably will never had any exclusion, it makes more sense to me to have an exclusion table.

If anyone has an idea of how to do this better, it would be great.

At the moment, I also have a 'calendar' table, which I join to based on the start/end date of the person's schedule to get the daily rate. So, I could then join to the exclusion date as well, to see if there is an override of the rate?

Issues I might find with my design, are a lot of the joins are based on:

```
 ON DateValue BETWEEN Start AND End
```

And I am not sure they're the most efficient joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the exception could be one or more period of times (one-to-many) for one project then your design using an exclusion table is the best design.

Example:

```
June 1, 2013 to June 30, 2013
```

Exclusion:

```
June 9, 2013 - 0 Rate
June 25 to 27 - 30% of Original Rate
```

However, if the exclusion is possible and can only be a maximum of ONE single period (or one-to-one type of relationship) then you might instead put it on the same fields as other fields on project table.

Example:

```
June 1, 2013 to June 30, 2013
```

Exclusion:

```
June 9, 2013 - 0 Rate
```

Comment: Yeah, it would be one to none or many. Most cases, there's no exclusion. Sometimes, there's one exception for a resource. Less of the time, but it can happen that they might say that "For the 6 weeks you have the resource, he will be charged at $100/hours. For the last week, you can have him for free ($0/hour). As he's new to the project, you can have him for half price for the first week ($50/hour). So, I think the design would work well for that. There would be two exclusion entries... One for the half price period, and one for the free period.

Comment: @Craig: if that's the case then as I've mentioned your design is the best solution that I know, namely, by adding an exclusion or exception table for certain dates with either 0 or lesser than original rate.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this "exclusion" table as single storage for person-project occupation data. In case when person is assigned to project one time without changes in rate, you will have one record in this table. In other cases you will have a history of rate changes in this table.

Comment: I don't quite follow. So, 99% of the time, a person is assigned to a project, and is billed for for the duration. But sometimes, a person will join a project for three weeks, but the consultancy decides to say that for the last 3 days of the three weeks, the client has him for free. So, the plan was to have an exclusing table, with a start/end date and a rate. In this case, the start and would cover the three days, and the 'rate' would be 0.

Comment: In the case of the worker joining the project for 3 weeks, why don't you simply have a table with two entries, one for the duration of the first 2½ weeks at the normal rate, and one for the last 3 days at the 0 rate? In the normal (99%) case, you'd simply have one entry per person for the whole duration.

Comment: How project-person relation is implemented in your db?

Comment: I just don't like the idea of "exclusions" in db. What I mean that you could have tables for person, project and occupation. Then occupation table would hold the data we are talking about.

Comment: It's more a resource, associated to a project. And then a person is assigned to the resource. So, a project has a Project Manager (that's the resource), and the resource is charged at $110/hour. The resource is there for 8 hours/day. A person can then be assigned to the role, but has no baring on the charge. So, a resource has a ProjectId (Liking to the project table), a StartDate, EndDate and a HourlyRate, as well as 'EcpectedHoursPerDay'.

Comment: I see, athabaska. The reason I was thinking of exclusion, is because it's an edge case. between 95 and 100% of the time, a person is assigned, and that's it. Sometimes, the client gets a person for free for a few days. So, because it's a case that doesn't happen often, it's more an 'opt-out'. The design has tables for everything. A Project, has Resources, which is linked to a Person.

Comment: @Craig: Another possibility would be to analyse all special cases first, then cater for them with specific tables. Example: A table for assigning people to a project for a single time-span, a table for "absences" (for free days, vacations, etc.; whatever gets treated the same way). Con: When you need to figure out the rate for any given timespan, you will need to check all these separate tables in the right order; perhaps a `JOIN` or `EXCEPT` clause will suffice. Pro: You do not need to store exclusions, or "negative facts". Plus you possibly have a "cleaner", easier-to-understand schema.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your are allowing discount on standard rate to the customer for specific period. for such case,  you can set the rate to be negative eg.-$100/hours for the duration to set resource rate for free in your discount/exclusion table. you can find the final rate for that resource for particular period by adding your discount amount and standard amount to get net amount. In your design, you have already mentioned the relation  will be made between exclusion and person assignment table. your design will allow to show what discount has been given to the customer. This approach is ok when your are adjusting the billing for exception cases.

In case, your are trying to do correction in project billing, IMO, you should have separate entries in person assignment table for each rate with the duration.

While generating Invoice to the customer, you can show  adjusted discounted rate or new revised billing based on the correction.